# How does an Animagus transform back into their human form?

Tags: harry-potter

If I remember correctly in PoA during the scenes at the Shrieking Shack, Wormtail was able to escape but to transform into his Animagus form he needed a wand.  However, we never see another wizard (McGonagall/Sirius) need to do this.

**When is a wand needed for Animagus transformations?**

*Update due to answers and comments:*

In the film he shown to touch his wand to his head. [Clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-agTClDfpcQ&start=26&end=40)

Comment: If you're asking specifically about the movie version (where Pettigrew needs to touch a wand) then you should use the [tag:movie] tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Willing transformation as an Animagus [does not need a wand](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/97013/21192). Pettigrew needed a wand in his case because a spell was cast on him to transform him into his human form.

---

I think the reason that Pettigrew needed a wand *in this case* was because Sirius and Remus *forced* him to transform into a human:

> Black had already retrieved Severus’s wand from the bed. He approached Remus and the struggling rat, and his wet eyes suddenly seemed to be burning in his face.
>
> “Together?” he said quietly.
>
> “I think so,” said Remus, holding Scabbers tightly in one hand and his wand in the other. “On the count of three. One – two – THREE!”
>
> A flash of blue-white light erupted from both wands; for a moment, Scabbers was frozen in mid-air, his small black form twisting madly – Ron yelled – the rat fell and hit the floor. There was another blinding flash of light and then –
>
> It was like watching up a speeded-up film of a growing tree. A head was shooting up from the ground; limbs were sprouting; next moment, a man was standing where Scabbers had been, cringing and wringing his hands.
>
> *- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*

Since an (unknown) spell was cast on him to force him to return to human form, it can be assumed that he would not be able to transform back into animal form without first lifting that spell.

Comment: But he _didn’t_ need a wand to transform back. He grabbed Ron’s wand when he had the opportunity, used it to attack Ron and Crookshanks, and then transformed _after_ the wand had been shot back out of his hand. If he needed to somehow undo the force-reveal spell before transforming, we must assume he did so non-verbally in the few seconds he had the wand in his hand, because there’s no indication of it in the book.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet True. I think the book is a little ambiguous in this case. I think if he didn't need the wand, he could have transformed at will during Lupin's unwilling distraction. If movie evidence is allowed, however, Pettigrew is shown specifically to touch the wand to himself before transforming.

Comment: @FGreg Maybe Animagus magic works like Animorphs technology: After a set time it's either impossible to change back without external help?

Comment: Relevant youtube [clip from the movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-agTClDfpcQ&start=26&end=40)

Comment: Frankly, Sirius was able to transform without a wand, in order to escape from Azkaban. Unless, of course, we are to assume that the Ministry lets prisoners keep their wands.

Comment: @FGreg I wouldn't have said so. Ron and especially Crookshanks were very dangerous to him when he transformed. He had a split second to decide what he was gonna do, he chose to go for the wand and take out anyone who could be a danger to him before he escaped.

Answer (score 3):

I think you remember incorrectly:

> Pettigrew had dived for Lupin's dropped wand. Ron, unsteady on his bandaged leg, fell. There was a bang, a burst of light - and Ron lay motionless on the ground. Another bang - Crookshanks flew into the air and back to the earth in a heap.
>
> '*Expelliarmus!*' Harry yelled, pointing his own wand at Pettigrew; Lupin's wand flew high into the air and out of sight.
>
> 'Stay where you are!' Harry shouted, running forwards.
>
> Too late. Pettigrew had transformed.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* - p.279 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 20, *The Dementors' Kiss*

So I conclude that Pettigrew did not require a wand to perform the transformation.

The film is the film, but even having watched that clip, I don't see any sign of him performing any magic on himself.

To speak to why he wouldn't have just transformed immediately: In the initial stages after Lupin transformed, Lupin was as dangerous to Wormtail as anybody else - Wormtail was actually tied to Lupin. After Sirius had pulled Lupin away, Wormtail had, amidst all the panic and the adrenaline, to make a decision. Crookshanks, in particular, would have been very dangerous to him post transformation. In that moment, he chose to go for the wand and take out Crookshanks and Ron before transforming when he lost the wand. Presumably, had Harry not cast Expelliarmus against him, he would have taken out everybody else, too, before making his escape.

And so I remain of the opinion that your premise is incorrect. We see elsewhere that Sirius is able to transform into a dog in Azkaban without a wand, we see JK Rowling describe Animagi as:

> wizards who could transform at will into animals
>
> *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* - pp.83-4 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 6, *Talons and Tea Leaves*

What makes the Animagus transformation special is precisely that you can do it at will. Otherwise it's just human transformation which requires skill, but is not a special ability and does not require registration. Moody is able to transform Malfoy into a ferret, Krum (admittedly rather badly) attempts to turn himself into a shark.

And so I think, really, you're asking us to solve a problem that doesn't actually exist. The answer to your question:

**When is a wand needed for Animagus transformations?**

Is: It isn't. That's what makes the Animagus transformation interesting.

Comment: I've posted a [related question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117796/21192) specifically addressing the premise of this question.