# Are wands required for an animagus transformation? If so, how were they used in Azkaban? If not, why did Pettigrew need one?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore, sirius-black, animagi, azkaban

In chapter 20 of *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, it's made very clear that Peter Pettigrew needed a wand to use his animagus transformation and escape. However, one chapter earlier we learn that Sirius Black was using and reverting his animagus transformation inside of Azkaban. This gives us the absurd conclusion that Azkaban's prisoners have wands.

Clearly, something is wrong here. What's the solution? I could speculate that it can be done without a wand but Pettigrew, unlike Black, lacks the competence, but I'm hoping for something more solid and clearly present in the text.

Comment: Refresh my memory please! What about Chapter 20 makes it clear? My memory is more  of the movie where Sirius struck Wormtail with what seemed like an anti-animagus spell, then took his wand for good measure.

Comment: @Aww_Geez Chapter 20 is when Pettigrew gets away. I don't recall the movie matching that scene very closely.

Comment: Check this question out
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97010/animagi-sirus-specifically-and-wands?rq=1

Comment: *Au contraire*. It seems pretty clear from Chapter Twenty that Pettigrew only transformed **after** Harry disarmed him.